# Text spacing and alignment in table

Tags: tables

I made a table with the code below but there are some issues as follows:

1. The headings are not center aligned
2. the text in each row do not start at the same point
3. the spacing between the texts are too much. see image below:

[image]

This is my code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        \begin{center}
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
            \tabcolsep=0.11cm
            \begin{tabular}{m{0.15\linewidth}m{0.2\linewidth}m{0.2\linewidth}m{0.2\linewidth}m{0.2\linewidth}}
                \hline 
                \textbf{Stakeholder} & \textbf{Travel Time} & \textbf{Service Frequency} & \textbf{Accessibility} & \textbf{Operating Cost}\\ 
                \hline
                \textbf{User} & Prefers the most direct routes, in order to reduce travel time & Prefers high frequency service with little or no waiting time &Prefers high proximity and access to the infrastructure like stops and stations to their desired origins and destinations. & Desires the cheapest fare possible for each trip. \\ 
                \textbf{Operator} & Prefers to operate indirect routes, in order to maximize patronage. & Will offer service frequencies that will ensure a maximum utilization of resources and least operational cost. & Prefers central locations where more passengers can access the service irrespective of distance to individual origins and destinations & Desires competitive and profitable fares. \\ 
                \textbf{Agency} & Prefers a travel time that is in line with the agency’s policy. & Prefers service frequencies that reflects the strategic transit goal of the government. & Prefers infrastructure coverage that satisfies most of the community. & Willing to subsidize fares, in order to make it affordable for users and profitable for operators. \\  
                \hline 
            \end{tabular} 
            \caption{Different travel stakeholders and their perceived objectives \label{[Tab1.3:Expanded form of table one whowing more modes and their attributes]}}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When you have very narrow text, it is not a good idea to use justified text. The `ragged2e` package is useful here `>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{...}`. The Headings are not centered as you have not asked them to, they are just (here) a cell bold text in an `m` column, which is left aligned by default.

Comment: @daleif could you please add a simple implementation of your answer in code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tabular` environment is not guaranteed to fit inside the width of the textblock. (In fact, it's a bit too wide.) I recommend using a `tabualarx` environment instead. I would also recommend using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of using `\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,english]{report}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,babel}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % for columns 2 thru 5
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\bfseries\arraybackslash}X} % for header cells
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}C@{}}{#1}}
\hyphenation{infra-structure}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % default value: 6pt
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{4}{Y} @{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Stakeholder} &
        \mc{Travel Time} & \mc{Service Frequency} &
        \mc{Accessibility} & \mc{Operating Cost} 
        \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{User} & Prefers the most direct routes, in order to reduce travel time & Prefers high frequency service with little or no waiting time &Prefers high proximity and access to the infrastructure like stops and stations to their desired origins and destinations. & Desires cheapest fare possible for each trip. \\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{Operator} & Prefers to operate indirect routes, in order to maximize patronage. & Will offer service frequencies that will ensure a maximum utilization of resources and least operational cost. & Prefers central locations where more passengers can access the service irrespective of distance to individual origins and destinations. & Desires competitive and profitable fares. \\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{Agency} & Prefers a travel time that is in line with the agency’s policy. & Prefers service frequencies that reflects the strategic transit goal of the government. & Prefers infrastructure coverage that satisfies most of the community. & Willing to subsidize fares, in order to make it affordable for users and profitable for operators. \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Different travel stakeholders and their perceived objectives} 
        \label{Tab1.3} % there's no point in having an overly long \label
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mico. the tabularx package definitely works betters for this case!

Answer (score 3):

here is one. However, I'd recommend rewriting this anyway (no suggestions on how), this is never going to look good or be nice to read.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        \begin{center}
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
            \tabcolsep=0.11cm
            \begin{tabular}{ 
                >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash} m{0.15\linewidth}
                >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash} m{0.2\linewidth}
                >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash} m{0.2\linewidth}
                >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash} m{0.2\linewidth}
                >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash} m{0.2\linewidth}
              }
                \hline 
                \Centering \textbf{Stakeholder} 
                & 
                \Centering\textbf{Travel Time} 
                & 
                \Centering \textbf{Service Frequency} 
                & 
                \Centering \textbf{Accessibility} 
                & 
                \Centering \textbf{Operating Cost}
                \\ 
                \hline
                \textbf{User} & Prefers the most direct routes, in order to reduce travel time & Prefers high frequency service with little or no waiting time &Prefers high proximity and access to the infrastructure like stops and stations to their desired origins and destinations. & Desires the cheapest fare possible for each trip. \\ 
                \textbf{Operator} & Prefers to operate indirect routes, in order to maximize patronage. & Will offer service frequencies that will ensure a maximum utilization of resources and least operational cost. & Prefers central locations where more passengers can access the service irrespective of distance to individual origins and destinations & Desires competitive and profitable fares. \\ 
                \textbf{Agency} & Prefers a travel time that is in line with the agency’s policy. & Prefers service frequencies that reflects the strategic transit goal of the government. & Prefers infrastructure coverage that satisfies most of the community. & Willing to subsidize fares, in order to make it affordable for users and profitable for operators. \\  
                \hline 
            \end{tabular} 
            \caption{Different travel stakeholders and their perceived objectives \label{[Tab1.3:Expanded form of table one whowing more modes and their attributes]}}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to make all the rows text start at the same point, or is that what you imply by "needing a rewrite"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by starting at the same point? Try  `p{...}` instead of `m{...}`.  I would completely rethink this.

Comment: Your solution (which is, obviously, based on the OP's code) doesn't guarantee that the table fits inside with width of the texblock. Indeed, the table is currently a bit wider than the textblock.

Comment: @Mico that is of course due to the choices for the column width

Answer (score 2):

considering all comments + added rules from `booktabs` package + `thead` from `makecell`

**edit:**
and considering [mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) comment regarding table width. this can be simply accomplish with use `tabularx` table environment as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11] % for see the text width
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries} l
                *{4}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
                @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[b]{Stake\-\\holder} & \thead[b]{Travel Time} & \thead[b]{Service\\ Frequency} & \thead[b]{Accessibility} & \thead[b]{Operating Cost}\\
    \midrule
User        & Prefers the most direct routes, in order to reduce travel time & Prefers high frequency service with little or no waiting time &Prefers high proximity and access to the infrastructure like stops and stations to their desired origins and destinations. & Desires the cheapest fare possible for each trip. \\
    \addlinespace
Operator    & Prefers to operate indirect routes, in order to maximize patronage. & Will offer service frequencies that will ensure a maximum utilization of resources and least operational cost. & Prefers central locations where more passengers can access the service irrespective of distance to individual origins and destinations & Desires competitive and profitable fares. \\
    \addlinespace
Agency  & Prefers a travel time that is in line with the agency’s policy. & Prefers service frequencies that reflects the strategic transit goal of the government. & Prefers infrastructure coverage that satisfies most of the community. & Willing to subsidize fares, in order to make it affordable for users and profitable for operators. \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Different travel stakeholders and their perceived objectives
\label{[Tab1.3:Expanded form of table one whowing more modes and their attributes]}}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't guarantee that the table will actually fit inside the textblock. (Indeed, the table's a bit wider than the textblock.)

Comment: @mico, as usual ... you have right. i didn't give any attention to this. use of `tabularx` with combinationof `c` and `>{Raggedright}X` columns is far better. i will correct answer.